# specialized shared_ptr conversion C++0x

Tags: c++, class, c++11, type-conversion, shared-ptr

This could probably be generalized to any templated class, but I've run into this with  shared_ptr.
I have class system that goes like:

```
class A {
protected:
    // some data
}

class B : public A {
    // some access functions
}

class C : public A {
    // some other access functions
}
```

I'm using this concept because in my library I'm using set of functions that shouldn't be exposed to user, so I divide these functions into two interface classes. Now, I know I could use one class and friends but this would get ugly if more than one class needed to access those functions.

However, I have problem that those classes are passed arround in `shared_ptr` and I need to retain reference counts (as the data would get destroyed). Therefore I need to convert in this example `shared_ptr<B>` to `shared_ptr<C>` and vice versa. Does `shared_ptr` allow such thing if needed functions are provided and if so what are those? Constructor? Assign operator? Or do I need to go level higher and cast whole pointers instead of just content? I had no luck so far.

And yes if you have a better/more neat method for hiding certain functions I'll be glad to hear it, but I would like to have this question answered too.

Comment: Have you looked at anonymous namespaces? Internal linkage?

Comment: I'm using internal linkage to hide most of content but imagine 4th class D that contains B (which packs library internal functions). You can't hide it if it is already needed in header of other class. I've little experience with anon namespace, so I'll probably look more into it.

Comment: I meant _instead of_ this inheritance nonsense, not in addition to.

Comment: I see your point just not the way, maybe I'll look arround a bit more on this topic before I start something serious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `std::static_pointer_cast` and `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, from `<memory>`:

```
struct A {}; struct B : A {};

std::shared_ptr<B> p(std::make_shared<B>());
std::shared_ptr<A> q(std::static_pointer_cast<A>(p));
// now p and q **share** ownership over their pointed-to object.
```